# Adobe Acrobat XI Pro: any option to invoke OCR tool with a keyboard hotkey (shortuct) only without mouse

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, adobe-acrobat

**As surprising as it may sound, I could not find any option to run from keyboard a command to start OCR (Optical character recognition) operation for the current document.**

Many (actually the most) in operations commands Adobe Acrobat Professional XI can be run with a keyboard hotkey (shortcut) and/or via main menu accelerator keys, say, as a command "Create PDF from file" with a hotkey *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>* or keyboard accelerators *<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> -> <kbd>R</kbd> -> <kbd>F</kbd>*. So if you your mouse fails to work, you will be however able to fulfill the most commands using the keyboard only.

But seems, that is does not apply to OCR. You can use accelerators **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**(iew) -> **<kbd>T</kbd>**(ools) -> **<kbd>T</kbd>**(ext Recognition) in order to open Tools sidebar at the left edge of the window, but there is no option to get there a focus without mouse.

As I can not use my mouse just now, it is a real headache for me :(  Is there any solution?